# Factors dominating forces between acetone and chloroform

Tags: hydrogen-bond, dipole

What type of interaction is present between acetone and chloroform?

According to me, acetone has weak hydrogen-bonds with chloroform, the hydrogen on an electronegative atom has electron density that is getting pulled on by an electronegative atom nearby.

While there is weak hydrogen bonding present, are dipole interactions not more prevalent?

Comment: even weak Hydrogen bonds are way stronger than dipole interactions

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb Not necessarily - there is no threshold of how weak h-bond can be. While in past weak hydrogen bonds were ignored this case here is relatively weak, but quite real.